# why my react project always warning:Maximum update depth exceeded at Navigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**can someone help me why my project run a alots error about this?
I don't see any question about my codes.
[image]

Here is error:

*Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
at Navigate (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:161563:5)
at div
at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:168705:6)
at div
at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:168705:6)
at div
at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:168705:6)
at Product (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1761:5)
at section
at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:168705:6)
at Products
at div
at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:168705:6)
at ProductList
at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:161243:5)
at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:161692:5)
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:161623:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:159844:5)
at App*

here are the relative codes:
App.jsx.
This one is setting path for the route.

```
import React from 'react'
import Cart from './pages/Cart'
import Home from './pages/Home'
import Login from './pages/Login'
import Product from './pages/Product'
import ProductList from './pages/ProductList'
import Register from './pages/Register'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Navigate, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
const App = () => {
  const user = true;
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/"  element={<Home />} />
        <Route exact path="/products/:category" element={<ProductList />} />
        <Route exact path="/product/:id" element={<Product />} />
        <Route exact path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
        <Route exact path="/register" element={user ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Register />} />
        <Route exact path="/login" element={user ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
}
export default App
```

Product.jsx This one is running product information,it's also a component.
**When I run the url:http:localhost:3000/products/women,it should be show the products belongs to the category:women.**But it runs  http:localhost:8000/products/productId,it's wrong.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Product from './Product';
import axios from "axios"
const Products = ({ cate, filters, sort }) => {
  //const Products = () => {
  console.log(cate, filters, sort)
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = () => {
      const res = axios.get(
        cate ? `http://localhost:8000/api/products?category=${cate}`
          : "http://localhost:8000/api/products")
        .then(
          function (res) {
            setProducts(res.data);
            console.log(res)
          }
        ).catch(
          function (err) {
            console.log(err)
          });
    }
    getProducts();
  }, [cate]);
  useEffect(() => {
    cate && setFilteredProducts(
      products.filter((item) => (
        Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) => {
          return item[key].includes(value);
        }
        )
      ))
    )
  }, [products, cate, filters])
  useEffect(() => {
    if ((sort === "newest")) {
      setFilteredProducts((prev) =>
        [...prev].sort((a, b) => a.createdAt.localeCompare(b.createdAt))
      )
    } else if (sort === "asc") {
      setFilteredProducts((prev) =>
        [...prev].sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price)
      )
    } else {
      setFilteredProducts((prev) =>
        [...prev].sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price)
      )
    }
  })
  return (
    <Container >
        {cate
        ? filteredProducts.map((item) => (
          <Product item={item} key={item._id} />))
        : products.slice(0, 8).map((item) => <Product item={item} key={item._id} />)}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

pages/Product.jsx.
This one is running display part.
http:localhost:3000/product/productID**

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { publicRequest } from './requestMethods';
const Product = () => {
   // 回傳路徑
    const location = useLocation();
    const id = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
    const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        const getProduct = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await publicRequest.get("/product/find/" + id);
                setProduct(res.data);
            }
            catch { }
}
        getProduct();
    }, [id])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the missing dependencies in the `useEffect` dependency array if not any, you can have an empty array `[]` as dependency

I could see a missing dep here in below effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (sort === "newest") {
    setFilteredProducts((prev) =>
      [...prev].sort((a, b) => a.createdAt.localeCompare(b.createdAt))
    );
  } else if (sort === "asc") {
    setFilteredProducts((prev) => [...prev].sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price));
  } else {
    setFilteredProducts((prev) => [...prev].sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price));
  }
},[sort]); // here `sort` is missing as dependency
```

Otherwise it runs on every render, which is what exactly the warning is about

Comment: I have a qusestion too.No matter I run http:localhost:3000/product/categoryName,it all redirects http:localhost:3000/product/productID**

Comment: @Anna Did you mean to really navigate to `"/products/categoryName"`? It's different than the `"/product/:id"` path. In other words, it's "product***s***" vs "product" in the declared route paths.

Comment: I know I navigate "/products/categoryName" but it still redirect "/products**/id",but I don't know why.

Comment: @KcH I rewrite the question you reply but it still appears the same 9 errors.

Comment: you might want to create a new Q I guess ... to the Q mentioned did it appear same ? also as Drew mentioned it's clear the `s` difference b/w `product` & `products` ... also it's not required to have `exact` prop, as it is by default in V6

Comment: Totally having 2 question:first is above and second is the url redirect question.

Comment: so if one is clear, make it a new Q for the other  .... sorry, it's not the way this site works, thanks

Comment: Okay,it's fine.Maybe I give the img url for the error screenshots?

Comment: like I said, you can ask a new Question altogether ...

Comment: I make a  question for it:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73923940/redirect-wrong-pages-and-url