# Redirect wrong pages and url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

As you can see the photo:

When I input the http:localhost:3000/ or some else url.
It all be redirected the wrong web:http:localhost:3000/product/**productID**

[image]
here are the relative codes:
App.jsx.
This one is setting path for the route.

```
import React from 'react'
import Cart from './pages/Cart'
import Home from './pages/Home'
import Login from './pages/Login'
import Product from './pages/Product'
import ProductList from './pages/ProductList'
import Register from './pages/Register'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Navigate, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
const App = () => {
  const user = true;
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/"  element={<Home />} />
        <Route exact path="/products/:category" element={<ProductList />} />
        <Route exact path="/product/:id" element={<Product />} />
        <Route exact path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
        <Route exact path="/register" element={user ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Register />} />
        <Route exact path="/login" element={user ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
}
export default App
```

Product.jsx This one is running product information,it's also a component.

**When I run the url:http:localhost:3000/products/women,it should be show the products belongs to the category:women.**

But it runs  http:localhost:3000/products/productId,it's wrong.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Product from './Product';
import axios from "axios"
const Products = ({ cate, filters, sort }) => {
  //const Products = () => {
  console.log(cate, filters, sort)
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = () => {
      const res = axios.get(
        cate ? `http://localhost:8000/api/products?category=${cate}`
          : "http://localhost:8000/api/products")
        .then(
          function (res) {
            setProducts(res.data);
            console.log(res)
          }
        ).catch(
          function (err) {
            console.log(err)
          });
    }
    getProducts();
  }, [cate]);
  useEffect(() => {
    cate && setFilteredProducts(
      products.filter((item) => (
        Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) => {
          return item[key].includes(value);
        }
        )
      ))
    )
  }, [products, cate, filters])
  useEffect(() => {
    if ((sort === "newest")) {
      setFilteredProducts((prev) =>
        [...prev].sort((a, b) => a.createdAt.localeCompare(b.createdAt))
      )
    } else if (sort === "asc") {
      setFilteredProducts((prev) =>
        [...prev].sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price)
      )
    } else {
      setFilteredProducts((prev) =>
        [...prev].sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price)
      )
    }
  },[sort])
  return (
    <Container >
        {cate
        ? filteredProducts.map((item) => (
          <Product item={item} key={item._id} />))
        : products.slice(0, 8).map((item) => <Product item={item} key={item._id} />)}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

pages/Product.jsx.
This one is running display part.
http:localhost:3000/product/productID**

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { publicRequest } from './requestMethods';
const Product = () => {
   // 回傳路徑
    const location = useLocation();
    const id = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
    const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        const getProduct = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await publicRequest.get("/product/find/" + id);
                setProduct(res.data);
            }
            catch { }
}
        getProduct();
    }, [id])
```

ProuctList.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { mobile } from './../responsive'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';


const ProductList = () => {

    //回傳路徑
    const location = useLocation();
    const cate = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
    console.log(location);
    //設定selector的值，並且回傳
    const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});
    const [sort, setSort] = useState("newest");

    const handleFilters = (e) => {

        const value = e.target.value;
        setFilters({
            ...filters,
            [e.target.name]: value,
        });
    };
    console.log(filters)

    return (
        <Container>
            <Navbar />
            <Announcement />
            <Title>Dresses</Title>

            <FilterContainer>
                <Filter><FilterText>Filter Products:</FilterText>
                    <Select name="color" onChange={handleFilters}>
                        <Option disabled>Color</Option>
                        <Option>black</Option>
                        <Option>white</Option>
                        <Option>green</Option>
                        <Option>wheat</Option>
                        <Option>black</Option>
                        <Option>red</Option>
                        <Option>blue</Option>

                    </Select>
                    <Select name="size" onChange={handleFilters}>
                        <Option disabled>Size</Option>
                        <Option>XS</Option>
                        <Option>S</Option>
                        <Option>M</Option>
                        <Option>L</Option>
                        <Option>XL</Option>

                    </Select></Filter>
                <Filter><FilterText>Sort Products:
                    <Select onChange={(e) => setSort(e.target.value)}>
                        <Option value="newest">Newest</Option>
                        <Option value="asc">Price(asc)</Option>
                        <Option value="desc">Price(desc)</Option>


                    </Select></FilterText></Filter>

            </FilterContainer>
            <Products cate={cate} filters={filters} sort={sort} />
            <NewsLetter />
            <Footer />

        </Container>
    )
}
```

I found that the bottom code will make the all pages redirect to the http:localhost:3000/product/productID

components/Product.jsx

```
const Product = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <Container className='container product'>
      <Circle />
      <Img src={item.img} />

      <Info >
        <Icon >
          <ShoppingCartOutlinedIcon />
        </Icon>
        <Icon>
          <Navigate to={`/product/${item._id}`}>
          <SearchOutlinedIcon />
          </Navigate>
        </Icon>
        <Icon>
          <FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon />
        </Icon>
      </Info>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Comment: It matches this `<Route exact path="/products/:category" element={<ProductList />} />` and so `ProductList` would render as a result .. not sure what issue you are facing ...

Comment: Yes, based on the URL in the image the `"/products/:category"` path is matched and the `ProductList` component is rendered. It's not clear what you are saying is an issue here. How did you effect a navigation from `"/products/women"` to `"/products/923983989832402309"` (*sorry, just typing in a garbage id, but you get the idea*), and why is that an issue? Again, as I pointed out in your previous question, are you really trying to link to `"/product/923983989832402309"`, i.e. a single product?

Comment: @DrewReese  I type "/products/women" but it automatically redirect to the "/products/923983989832402309"(It's not my setting). I found that all pages will be redirected the code of components/Product.jsx

Comment: @KcH I type "/products/women" but it automatically redirect to the "/products/923983989832402309"(It's not my setting). I found that all pages will be redirected the code of components/Product.jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Product` component is rendering a `Navigate` component to `"/product/XXX"` when it is rendered. Rendering `<Navigate />` will immediately effect a navigation action. It seems this `Product` component is rendered as part of a list when rendering all the products. It's likely you meant to render a `Link` component instead so the navigation isn't effected until the search icon is clicked.

```
const Product = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <Container className='container product'>
      <Circle />
      <Img src={item.img} />

      <Info >
        <Icon >
          <ShoppingCartOutlinedIcon />
        </Icon>
        <Icon>
          <Link to={`/product/${item._id}`}> // <-- use Link component
            <SearchOutlinedIcon />
          </Link>
        </Icon>
        <Icon>
          <FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon />
        </Icon>
      </Info>
    </Container>
  );
};
```